# Using large record set with QTableView and QAbstractTableModel -- retrieve visible rows only

Tags: python, mysql, qt, pyqt

I'm using PyQt and showing a table of data in a QTableView. I'm simply looking for a way to avoid calling the ENTIRE data set into memory when no more than 100 lines will ever appear on the screen. Theoretically, I should be able to browse a table containing hundreds of thousands of records nearly instantly, if I'm just retrieving the visible data.

So as I understand it, when the QTableView wants to show a cell of data, it calls the "data()" function of my table model (which subclasses QAbstractTableModel). That function receives the row and column index of the cell that's supposed to show. This works great for me if I have already loaded all the data I need.

BUT if I don't have all the data yet, won't I have to make a query for each cell? Is there another way to do this? Perhaps there's a way to grab data row-by-row instead of cell-by-cell. Perhaps there's a database-specific solution for MySql, which is what we're using.

Comment: Why not use [QSqlTableModel](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html)?

Comment: Does that load only what's visible? That's good to know, and I'll research that, but I would very much like to understand how to implement this with QAbstractTableModel (of which QSqlTableModel is a subclass). I didn't mention this in my question, but I might need to do the same thing for large CSV files where I don't want to load the entire file into memory.

Comment: I don't have any personal experience of using it, but it surely must be faster than a custom model implemented in PyQt. If you want to know in detail how it's done, you will probably have to read the relevant Qt source code. Or for more general guidance, try the [Model subclassing reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference).

Comment: Well, I reject that QSqlTableModel is doing anything too unusual. It's not that rendering rows is slow for me. I'm just trying to figure out a methodology for making appropriate database calls from the view. This is a generic enough problem that I was hoping for some kind of generic solution.

Comment: I just meant that subclassing `QSqlTableModel` might be more performant that writing the whole thing from scratch based on `QAbstractTableModel`.  But like I say, I haven't actually used it, so maybe there's not that much to be gained.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there's a `prefetch()` function in QSqlQueryModel which creates row indices and does a `query.seek()` for a particular row if it's not loaded already. That prefetch function is used by the `data()` call, which is called by the QTableView. When I get time, I'll try to craft a simple implementation example, unless someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely doable.  I use this technique to scroll pandas tables with tens or even hundreds of thousands of rows without a hitch.  Like you said you will need to use [QAbstractTableModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstracttablemodel.html) to subclass your data into.

Code can look big but the key here is to remember that the workhorse part of the code is the "data" which is called for each **visible** cell of data.

Something similar to:

```
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, datain, headerdata, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.arraydata = datain
        self.headerdata = headerdata

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()
        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return QVariant(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        elif role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(str(self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()]))
        return QVariant()
```

The active widget is will be a subclass of QWidget with an `__init__` something like:

```
class DbsVarWindow(QWidget):
    """Display a Qt window of a Zacks Dbs Var. inputs:
        * fname file name (full path) of the dbs file
        * vname var name (openvest munged name' to display"""
    def __init__(self, fname, vname,  *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        dbs = ZacksDbs(fname)
        vals = dbs.get(vname)#[:,:10]
        tickers = dbs.get('ticker')

        # set the title
        self.setWindowTitle(vname)
        # set the minimum size
        self.resize(800, 600)

        # set the model and table view settings
        tablemodel = MyTableModel(vals,tickers, self)
        tableview = QTableView()
        # try some sorting
        tableview.setSortingEnabled(True)
        # allow drag to rearrange columns
        tableview.horizontalHeader().setMovable(True)
        tableview.setModel(tablemodel)
        # set the font
        font = QFont("Courier", 12, 1)
        tableview.setFont(font)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(tableview)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()
```

The line with `tableview.setModel(tablemodel)` is what hooks your data (tablemodel) to the widget.

Apologies if the code is too much.  This is as close to a caononical example as I could scrape up.

Comment: This is VERY close to what I'm doing already. It's not that SHOWING the records is slow. It's that the `data()` function call expects that the entire record set is already loaded into `self.arraydata`. And THAT is slow. Right now I'm investigating how QSqlTableModel pulls only the data it needs to show on the screen.

Comment: @TheGern depending on your exact data size, usually 1 query to get all indicies (in your sorted order) will suffice.  Then when you get the data() call, you check a local cache of "full" records and run a 50 record sql query to refresh your local cache.    Sorry that's not more specific but it really depends on what works for your data scheme.

Comment: That is in fact one of the paths I was investigating! But check my last comment to my OP -- QSqlQueryModel does it by fetching one row at a time, according to what is viewable. I just need to figure out how to implement a simple version into my subclass of QAbstractTableModel.